# I cannot upload variables to database

Tags: php, sql, insert, sql-insert

I tried to upload video filenames and other variables to the database, but the insert statement won't work. Anyway the *videofile-name* and the *thumbnail-filename* are both uploaded to the right folders.
I've checked and there's nothing wrong with the sql statement. But why won't it work can anyone tell me?

**PHP code**

```
<?php

    session_start();

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $videoName = $_POST['videoName'];
    $videoDesc = $_POST['description'];
    $category = $_POST['category'];
    $level = $_POST['level'];
    $userId = $_SESSION['userId'];

    $videoFile = $_FILES["videoFile"];
    $videoFileName = $videoFile['name'];
    $videoFileType = $videoFile['type'];
    $videoFileTempName = $videoFile['tmp_name'];
    $videoFileError = $videoFile['error'];

    $videoFileExt = explode(".", $videoFileName);
    $videoFileActualExt = strtolower(end($videoFileExt));
    $videoAllowed = array("mp4", "mov", "avi");

    $thumbFile = $_FILES["thumbnail"];
    $thumbFileName = $thumbFile["name"];
    $thumbFileType = $thumbFile["type"];
    $thumbFileTempName = $thumbFile["tmp_name"];
    $thumbFileError = $thumbFile["error"];

    $thumbFileExt = explode(".", $thumbFileName);
    $thumbFileActualExt = strtolower(end($thumbFileExt));
    $thumbAllowed = array("jpg", "jpeg", "png");





    if (in_array($videoFileActualExt, $videoAllowed)) {
        if(in_array($thumbFileActualExt, $thumbAllowed)) {
            if ($videoFileError === 0) {
                if ($thumbFileError === 0) { 

                            $videoFullName = $videoFile . "." . uniqid("", true) . "." . $videoFileActualExt;
                            $videoFileDestination = "../video/" . $videoFullName;

                            $thumbFullName = $thumbFile . "." . uniqid("", true) . "." . $thumbFileActualExt;
                            $thumbFileDestination = "../thumbnail/" . $thumbFullName;


                            include 'dbh.inc.php';

                            if(empty($videoName) or empty($videoDesc)) {
                                header("Location: ../uploadVideo.php?upload=empty");
                                exit();
                            } else {
                                    move_uploaded_file($videoFileTempName, $videoFileDestination);
                                    move_uploaded_file($thumbFileTempName, $thumbFileDestination);

                                $sql = "INSERT INTO video (filnavn, thumbnail, videoName, descript, idMusician, categoryName, idLevel) VALUES ('$videoFullName', '$thumbFullName', '$videoName', '$videoDesc', $userId, '$category', $level);";
                                mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

                                    header("Location: ../uploadVideo.php?upload=success");
                                    exit();
                                }

                } else {
                    echo "You had a thumbnail error!";
                    exit();
                }
            } else {
                echo "You had a video error!";
                exit();
            }
        } else {
            echo "You need to upload a proper thumbnail file type";
            exit();
        }
    } else {
        echo "You need to upload a proper video file type!";
        exit();
    }
} else {

}
```

Comment: did you get any error here ?

Comment: No, got sent back to the upload website with upload success message. But the Insert won't work.

Comment: try this one to get the error :
**mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die('MySQL Error: '.mysqli_error($conn).' ('.mysqli_errno($conn).')');**

Comment: Do you want to have SQL injections? Because this is how you get SQL injections. Please use prepared statements or PDOs when you want to store data received from the outside in your database.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot insert `or` in this way in the `if()` condition, you must always use the logical operator as

```
 if(empty($videoName) || empty($videoDesc))
```

Because of that your execution of code must have stopped at that point.

Comment: Both are valid.

Comment: are your files getting uploaded by this function ` move_uploaded_file($videoFileTempName, $videoFileDestination);
                                    move_uploaded_file($thumbFileTempName, $thumbFileDestination);`

Comment: Yes they are uploaded to the folders.

Comment: Ok your query is perfectly fine please check for the types of each filed in the table is it correct for example`int` or `float`